# retrieve "Link Color" value

Tags: php, customization, color-picker, get-theme-mod

I've set the Link color using the color picker in the front end. I want to use this color for buttons on the site so I used the following code in header.php

```
<style>
.btn{
    background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'link_color' ); ?>;
}
</style>
```

It worked and I could see the buttons change color to whatever I picked for `Link Color` setting.
But it shows up only in Customization window. When I hit *Publish* and reload the site, I see the function is not returning any value.

```
<style>
.btn{
    background-color: ;
}
</style>
```

This is what I see when I inspect element.

**Also**, I've used

```
.site,body{
    background-color: #<?php echo get_theme_mod('background_color'); ?>!important;
}
```

in `header.php` and it loads the color properly. I can used `background_color` , `page_background_color`, `secondary_text_color` with `get_theme_mod` and also `get_option` functions but not `link_color` or `main_text_color`.

How do I retrieve `Link Color` ?

Comment: Are you sure it was saved to begin with? You're retrieving the value correctly from what I see, but without the code that registers and creates the customiser control no further debugging can occur

Comment: try `$bg_color = get_theme_mod( 'link_color' ); var_dump($bg_color);`